# opencv and python in osx - but how?

Tags: python, macos, import, opencv, computer-vision

I tried to install opencv and python with port and brew.
but when i try `import cv` it says "module not found".

i have the same problem on my windows machine and just no solution works.
is there a simple step by step solution for someone who does not know all the terminal codes?
im not really a good programmer but it would be awsome to get this working.

--edit--

got it working on Windows and Mac

**Mac:** First uninstalled Homebrew and MacPort
restarted, installed Macport again.
then :

```
sudo port install opencv +universal +python26
```

after that i just had to install numpy.

**Win7**

installed

```
python-2.7.2.msi
OpenCV-2.2.0-win32.exe
opencv-python-2.2.0.win32-py2.7.exe
numpy-1.6.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using brew, try `brew info opencv`, which explicitly tells you:

> The OpenCV Python module will not work until you edit your PYTHONPATH like so:
>   export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"

The export thing should go into your shell config. You could put this into ~/.bashrc, but the truly system-wide setting would need to be set otherwise (try [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)).

Or else, in your python script:

> `import sys` 
>   `sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/")` 
>   `import cv`

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way (imo) is using macports - once you did setup macports, installing opencv with python is:

```
port install opencv +python27
```

(you may need to uninstall opencv first if you already installed it without python support), Then use macport's python (not the system one) - should be in `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`, you can add that to your path so you don't need to type the full one.

Comment: what i would like to do is start from zero. so uninstall al python and opencv things i installed. is that possible?

Comment: Python comes with OSX, you don't want to get rid of that. For the brew/port things, they have uninstall commands.

Comment: How can i install al the things in 32 bit?